# Update XML element

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, powershell-2.0

Given the following XML:

```xml
<data>  
   <variable>
    <row>
      <column1>RPS</column>
      <column2>10</column>
    </row>  
  </variable>

  <variable>
    <row>
      <column1>SANTH</column>
      <column2>5000</column>
    </row>  
  </variable> 
</data>
```

I need to read the value 5000 and need to replace with some random number. I am I not having any clue. Below code copied from net. It's not working as per my requirement.

```bsh
$variable = Get-Random

[xml]$xml = Get-Content D:\test.xml
$xml.data.variable.row.ChildNodes.Item(1)."#text" = "$variable" // failing  here 
$xml.Save('D:\test.xml')
```

Also, Plese let me know how to access the column2 by giving element name rather giving index value.

Comment: would you consider writing some simple code piece to solve this problem?

Comment: yeah. I am use this as sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML data has more than one `<variable>` node, so `$xml.data.variable` produces a list of nodes. PowerShell v2 doesn't transparently unroll lists/arrays to allow access to the members of each element. Instead you're trying to access a (non-existing) property `row` of the array of `<variable>` nodes.

This should work if you want to modify the `<column2>` child node of the second `<variable>` node:

```
$xml.data.variable[1].row.column2 = "$variable"
```

If you want to modify the child node whose value is 5000 (regardless of its position) you're probably better off using an [XPath](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.3/expressions.html) expression:

```
$xml.SelectSingleNode("//column2[text()='5000']").'#text' = "$variable"
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Its woked :)     <ApplicationRevision>96</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.2.3.%2a</ApplicationVersion>. Do you aware the significance of each ? and here % 2a means what ?

Comment: How would I know? The XML snippet is different from what you posted in your question, and I have no idea what you're inserting or where that value comes from.

Comment: Sorry..!!   could you please tell why this if stament not get hit.   ApplicationRevision here 96 and ApplicationVersion= 1.2.3.%2a

Comment: [xml]$xml = Get-Content C:\RAJA\CI\cp\cp.csproj
$PropertyRevision = $xml.Project.PropertyGroup[0].ApplicationRevision
$a=0
If($PropertyRevision -gt "95")
{
$a=1
}
$xml.Save('C:\RAJA\CI\cp\cp.csproj')

Comment: Please post a new question with your actual XML structure and your actual code.